# Calculo de raiz cubica em vetores

Tags: c, array, loop, matemática

Olá! Estou fazendo um exercicio onde é preciso calcular a raiz cubica de 10 números armazenados num vetor e tranferi-los de vetor A (onde os nºs foram lidos) para vetor B ( onde eles estarão transformados no cubo de A, porém isso é feito em outra função). o problema é que meu programa não está fazendo essa conversão. tentei adicionar uma 3ª variavel C mas não adiantou
O codigo é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define tam 10

void cubo(int *B);

int main(){
    int A[tam], B[tam];

    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
    cubo(A);
    return 0;
}
void cubo(int *B){
  long C[tam];
    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        C[i] = sqrt(sqrt(B[i]));
        printf("%d\n", B[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Matematicamente não creio que a raiz quadrada da raiz quadrada seja a raiz cúbica de um número. Talvez você possa utilizar `pow(B[i], 1.0/3.0)` e imprimir não o parâmetro mas sim o resultado da operação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer a raiz cúbica, não adianta fazer `sqrt(sqrt(numero))`, pois a raiz quadrada da raiz quadrada é a raiz quarta.

Não há uma função pronta para a raiz cúbica, mas sabemos que a raiz N de um número é o mesmo que esse número elevado a 1 / N, então você pode usar `pow(numero, 1.0 / 3.0)` para calcular.

O problema é que a raiz cúbica não necessariamente será um número inteiro, então eu sugiro mudar o tipo de `b` para `float`. Além disso, se quer jogar os números de `a` para `b`, então ambos teriam que ser parâmetros da função (além da quantidade de itens, que eu acho melhor ser um parâmetro do que depender da constante - nesse caso não faria diferença, mas em uma função mais geral, eu faria assim):

```
#define TAM 10

void raizCubica(int*a, float *b, int qtd){
    for(int i = 0; i < qtd; i++){
        b[i] = pow(a[i], 1.0 / 3.0);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[TAM];
    float b[TAM];

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    raizCubica(a, b, TAM);

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf("%.5f\n", b[i]); // imprimir com 5 casas decimais
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Também mudei o nome da função, já que cubo não é o mesmo que raiz cúbica. E fiz a função apenas guardar os valores em `b` (a impressão pode ser feita depois, a função só calcula e guarda no array - e fiz assim também para mostrar que os valores foram de fatos colocados em `b`).